# Python is not responding. I am trying to write some basic code on windows

Tags: python, pygame

So, I wrote this code, and it really should work. The main problem is that the code just stops responding when it opens a window and runs.

```
bif = "back.jpeg"
mif = "image2.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Also, I am getting this error in IDLE.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Documents\game\Game", line 10, in <module>
    background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
error: Couldn't open back.jpeg
```

Comment: `sys.exit` should be `sys.exit()` for one. Same for `pygame.quit`: `pygame.quit()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running your code, you have to make sure it runs in the right working directory. That would be why it doesn't find the image.

Since you're running your code in IDLE, the terminal will probably keep the process alive, so that the window won't close after the error (it would if the program terminated). Since it doesn't run event.get regularly, windows will notice that it isn't responding and that's what you're getting.

To find out what directory your script is running from, print the output of os.getcwd().

If you don't want to fiddle with paths yet and just have it run, why not set an absolute path for the image for now, like "C:\Users\My Name\Projects\Python\back.jpeg".

Comment: Well, i printed the output of os.getcwd, and it just gave the this: <built-in function getcwd>. Also, I made sure that the .py of the script is in the same directory as my images. Apologies for my noobienes. I am pretty new to python.

Comment: The reason it gives you "function getcwd" is that you just evaluated the name "getcwd", rather than executing the function to get the value. To get the value from the function, you write () after it

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.quit
sys.exit
```

should be

```
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

and

```
screen.blit(mouse_c(x,y))
```

should be

```
screen.blit(mouse_c, (x,y))
```

also you may want to look into limiting it to a certain max frames a second (tutorial covers this)

Comment: Hey, I made the changes that you suggested.... But I am still getting the problem. I will make the changes to the question.... Also, I just noticed an error. I will update the OP with that too.

Comment: @user2562381 the error you added indicates it cant find your `back.jpeg` file or doesn't have rights to open it.  But that may be just because you were running from idle (current path can be different depending on what you actually run) But I would check is that really the files name? are you sure its in the right path (could use absolute paths to make sure)

Comment: @user2562381  In general a good debugging practice is to remove parts until it is working that add them back one at a time, then you know which addition broke it.  Since your proggy is so small maybe strip it down to the just init stuff, the quit handler, and the update call.  see if you can get that to work.

Comment: @everyone: The problem seems to be solved once I moved the project over to sublime text. IDLE be crazy.